# How to distinguish overlapped strings by regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, overlap

I want to find all four-letter strings in a sequence. The first letter is 'N', the second one is not 'P', the third one is 'S' or 'T' and the last one is not 'P'.

Here's my code:

```
import re
seq='NNSTQ'
glyco=re.findall('N[^P][S|T][^P]',seq)
print glyco
```

and the result is:

`['NNST']`

However, the expected output should be:

`['NNST','NSTQ']`

I think the problem is that these two strings have overlapped part, and re.findall() just skips the second one. What can I do to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `(?=...)` (lookahead assertion) instead, since `findall` only matches use the part of the string only once, with means, ignores overlapping:

```
import re
seq='NNSTQ'
glyco=re.findall('(?=(N[^P][S|T][^P]))',seq)
print (glyco) 
# prints ['NNST','NSTQ']
```

This will match everything even if it overlaps. As the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) stated:

> (?=...)
>
> Matches if ... matches next, but doesn’t consume any of the
>   string. This is called a lookahead assertion. For example, Isaac
>   (?=Asimov) will match 'Isaac ' only if it’s followed by 'Asimov'.

You can also check this for more info:

http://regular-expressions.mobi/lookaround.html?wlr=1

Answer (score 0):

`findall()` does not return overlapping matches, but there is nothing to stop you from explicitly searching for them, for example with:

```
def myfindall(p, s):
 found = []
 i = 0
 while True:
  r = re.search(p, s[i:])
  if r is None:
   break
  found.append(r.group())
  i += r.start()+1
 return found

seq='NNSTQ'
glyco=myfindall('N[^P][ST][^P]', seq)
```

Comment: How does your answer address the requirement that N is the first letter, etc?

Comment: edited to add an example of calling it with the pattern where N is the first letter